# Spring Batch with mongodb issue

Tags: spring-batch

I'm trying to poc spring batch with mongodb with simple logic.

- Read csv file
- Insert data to MongoDB

Question:

- Do i need relational database such as: Mysql for jobRepository?
- If relational database need, is there other way not to use relational database for jobRepository?
- Can someone provide code example for springbatch 5.0 mongodb without relational database ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you use `@EnableBatchProcessing`, you need to specify a datasource to configure a Jdbc-based JobRepository. This could be an in-memory database like H2 or HSQLDB.

Otherwise, you need to implement a `JobRepository` for MongoDB and set it on your jobs and steps. In this case, there is no need to provide a datasource. For the record, there is a feature request to support MongoDB as job repository, see [issue 877](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/877).